# javascript get non matching data from two array objects matching column, one column containing Pipe seperated record

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

i am stuck in a logic for getting record by checking Master data if it is present in the Pipe seperated column of one array and not present in another master data containing array, example code is below.Please help if you can.

```
var names = [
    {id:1, name:'Sandra|John', type:'user', username:'sandraJ'},
    {id:2, name:'John', type:'admin', username:'johnny2'},
    {id:3, name:'Peter|John', type:'user', username:'peteJ'},
    {id:4, name:'Bobby', type:'user', username:'be_bob'}
];
var master = [
    {id:1, value:'John'},
    {id:2, value:'Bobby'}
];
```

The Resultant array should be Result3 below.

```
var result3 = [
    {id:1, name:'Sandra'},
    {id:2, name:'Peter'}
];
```

i tried below code, but could not get the result.

```
var result = names.filter(function(o1){
                return !master.some(function(o2){
                    return SplitTheString(o1.name) === o2.value;
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) for that :

```
var result = names.filter(function(o1) {
  return !master.some(function(o2) {
    return o1.name.split('|').includes(o2.value);
  });
});
```

*PS : Here's the ES6 version, just because:*

```
let result = names.filter(o1 => !master.some(o2 => o1.name.split('|').includes(o2.value)));
```

Comment: Thanks Zenoo, it worked correctly, ES6 was gr8 too, thanks. :)

Comment: i am stuck at one more point, it would of great help if you can help, the above filter works if both the data of split has error, what to do if only one of the master value is wrong, please find fiddle for reference.http://jsfiddle.net/ASrUD/1657/

Comment: Hi, Got the solution, just need to replace the some with every while filtering the names array
    let result = names.filter(o1 => !master.every(o2 => o1.name.split('|').includes(o2.value)));